# Some questioning about codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I don't know if it's the good place to ask these questions. So if it's not the case  sorry for inconvenience.

We are looking for the most adapted tool for our crossplatform mobile project. Before begin to invest time we are testing many crossplatform develeoppement solution ... it's difficult to find the tool where you say Yes it this one !!

Actually we are beginning to test codename one. It looks very promising but we have some doubts and question about features and how we can organize our project :

Do you know if it is possible to separate code and design -> build each "screen of the app" with one xml file to describe components and style and one java class to define behavior and contents(dynamically or not) of these components ?

What about nfc support ? at least for android apps ?

The ui components are not really "sexy" in examples. Do you know if it is possible to load/download or why not buy some more attractive one.

I hope you will be able to answer our questions

Thank you and sorry for my english ...

Comment: I forgot to say Hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`build each "screen of the app" with one xml file` take a look at
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/gui-builder-walkthru.html

`What about nfc support ? at least for android apps ?` see here
https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-interface.html

`The ui components are not really "sexy" in examples.`
https://www.codenameone.com/gallery.html

But overall I would like to suggest you can't get 'that' sexy unless you not try. Don't take it wrong but see the examples submitted by other and what they developed you may get same or more than that if you try.

I hope you will be able to answer Your questions :)

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I seen the gallery that's why i say  that... I'll test some more.